# Change navigation logo on scroll

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a scrolling navigation menu (WP site). By default, my logo is green. When a user scrolls, a white background color appears.

But - on a few screens, I need the starting logo to be white. I have figured out how to create an alternative navigation, but I need that logo to go back to green once a user scrolls and the background color appears (this, I cannot figure out).

*I would guess the code is written something like, "if page uses AltNav, use logo-white on fixed navigation", but I don't know how to write that myself.*

**Navigation**

```
<nav class="nav <?php isAltNav() ? _e('alt-nav') : null; ?>" id="nav">
    <a class="nav-logo" href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/assets/img/logo-<?php _e(isAltNav() ? 'white' : 'green'); ?>.svg" alt="logo"></a>
</nav>
```

**Pages starting w/ white nav**

```
function isAltNav() {
    $_pages = array(
        'page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'
    );
}
```

**SCSS**

```
&-fixed {
    background-color: rgba($white, 0.95);
    color: $white !important;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the scrolling code?

Answer (score 1):

In WP each page has a class that you could use to change the background color of the logo, f.e.:

```
.id-11 .logo {
    background-colour: #FFF
}
```

And with jQuery you could use the scroll-event and change the background on scrolling:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.id-11 .logo').css('background-color','red');
});
```